# How to continue loop until true

Tags: python, loops, input

I am attempting to get a correct input but whilst the input is false I want it to continually ask again until the output is correct, how do I correctly do this?

```
x = input("Enter your string")
if set(x).issubset({'m', 'u', 'i'}):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
    x = input("Enter your string")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while not set(input("Enter your string")).issubset({'m', 'u', 'i'}):
    print("false")
else:
    print("true")
```

Comment: "just use the `not` operator and a `while` loop" might be worth adding to this answer since it is not immediately obvious.

Comment: Of course, that makes complete sense, is it common to create the true section in the else part of the statement?

Comment: I don't think it is uncommon, really. Thinking of it, it is just a condition. You can negate it to invert True or False. In fact, the `not` is not needed here, you could have the `print("true")` in the if and the other branch in the else. It is just a matter of readability / preference.

Answer (score 1):

This should do also:

```
while not set(input("Enter your string")).issubset({'m', 'u', 'i'}):
    print("false")
print("true")
```